# How do i prevent my CSS affecting external plugins?

Tags: css

As an example I got a css class which applies to all labels within my website.

```
label
{
 font-size: 18px;
}
```

Now after i install a external JS plugin i find that the plugin itself is affected by my base css.

```
<div>
    <div class="plugin" />
    <label>Xyz</label> 
    //Dynamic html inserted by plugin
</div>
```

The plugin has its own stylesheet so how can i prevent my base css style touching any elements within the plugin div?

**EDIT**

I must add that label was a very simple example.  The actual layout is more complex with global styles touching various elements.

Comment: Sounds like you either need to prefix your own `label` css so it only applies to your site (e.g. by adding a "#container" div and doing "#container label"), or modify the plugin css to compensate for your main css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make your css too general, try to be as specific as possible when you want to style only some of your elements. If you can't select your elements without affecting the plugin's elements add a class to them.

```css
label{ /* too general, don't use this */
 /* ... */
}
body > div > form > label{ /* more specific, but maybe still affecting your plugin */
 /* ... */
}

label.noplugin{ /* use a class on non-plugin elements */
 /* ... */
}

div:not(.plugin) > label{ /* affecting only children of div which are NOT
    tagged with the plugin class */
 /* ... */
}
```

So in your case a better way to style your label would be

```css
<div>
    <div class="plugin">
    <label>Xyz</label>
    //Dynamic html inserted by plugin
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
*:not(.plugin) > label
{
 font-size: 18px;
}
```

Please note that `:not` is unfortunately [not supported by IE ≤8](http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t37).

Comment: Unfortunately  it's an inherited website so css has already been written.  To much effort to change existing css.  Was hoping that there was something out there that can reset the css styles before plugin css kicks in...

Comment: @Fixer: Ouch, then you're probably doomed. You could tag your plugin elements with `.plugin` and reset every element with specific values, but this will take a lot of time.

Comment: @Fixer - the whole point of CSS is that it is easy to change (re-style your site with out changing your HTML structure etc). I don't think there is much you can do if you are not willing to change your CSS files. It is simple enough to do and you can open another Stack Overflow question if you need help making the changes.

Comment: I'm not totally resisting the changes.  But do you know of any solution that can use JS to "reset" the css for an element  then  apply the plugin css?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things.

i) Give your parent container ID

ii) And style child label of container.

Here is [fiddle workout](http://jsfiddle.net/MjUeu/).